# How to make the Primary Menu stay the same in the PC and mobile versions of the Twenty Sixteen theme

Tags: menus, templates, theme-twenty-sixteen

I'm new to WordPress, using which I was able to create this site over here: http://wtfai.pl/

It's almost complete, save for one change I would like to make: to make the Primary Menu stay exactly the same way it is visible now on PCs and mobile devices, so in a single line (it's just 3 positions after all), and aligned to center. I may perhaps want to shrink the text a little bit if it doesn't fit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add below css in your theme style.css file, change font size if you need

```
@media screen and (max-width: 56.875em) {
    .main-navigation li {
        float: left;
        width: 33.333333%;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

To make menu items inline apply floats on list elements not on nav tag
I checked using inspect elements and code i sent works fine. check that rule does not override by any other CSS in hierarchy.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work, even after changing the class to .site-header-menu. If this may help, here's everything I got so far in the additional CSS box:

[at]media all and (min-width: 44.375em) {
.site-header-main .site-branding {
margin: 0;
}

.site-header-menu {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.primary-menu {
width: auto;
}
}

#mobile-menu-trigger-wrap {
    display: none;
}

.site-footer {
  display: none;
}

[at]media screen and (max-width: 56.875em) {
    .site-header-menu {
        display: inline;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
}

Comment: Check update to answer